# How do i access camera video from phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Phonegap's documentation suggests that there is a single method to access the camera, camera.getPicture().

Now I would like to access the video feed and draw something on top. Is this possible?

Comment: Here is the documentation with an example. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo  Do you need more than that?

Answer (score 4):

I made a PhoneGap Plugin for iOS to capture video streaming into a canvas or image:
https://github.com/daraosn/Cordova-CanvasCamera

It's not the best way to do it (if you can, do it natively). I wouldn't recommend it for production apps yet, but it works good so far in development.

Comment: This is nice. I would like to see an example where you can stream the video into a video tag.